# How to efficiently select only the IDs of a Belongs To Many relationship in Eloquent?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

If I have a Users table and Tags table, and a pivot table for a Belongs To Many relationship, how do I use Eloquent to load only the IDs of the relation?

If I do `User::with('tags')`, this will do a join on the pivot table and also a join on the tags table. However, this is unnecessary and inefficient in my case, as I want to be able to only select the IDs of the tags from the pivot table, not the other columns in the Tags table. In other words, I only want it to do a single join from Users to Users_Tags.

Thank you.

Comment: You want to eager load those ids on multiple models?

Comment: Yes, I want to do this with multiple models (collection) or a single model. Thanks.

Comment: Without joining the pivot table you can't get the related tags because relation is stored in pivot table.

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha Yes I want to join the pivot table (Users_Tags) with the Users table. Not the Tags table with the pivot table.

Comment: To eager load this kind of relation you would need separate model for the pivot table. While this shouldn't be a problem, you could end up with inconsistent results, since there could be deleted tags that still have rows on the pivot table.

Comment: Agreed with `decoz`, very good point.

Comment: @deczo Perhaps that's the only way. How can the pivot table have deleted tags? Foreign key constraints should take care of that.

Comment: Basically there shouldn't be any row for deleted queries on pivot table but maybe it's better to use another `model` mapped to pivot table only for this.

Comment: @user371699 depends on your schema and db type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, since @WereWolf's suggestions are not correct (1st will cause error, 3rd might be wrong if there are custom keys), here are the options for you, that not fetch related models.

Starting with the most obvious:

```
// for single model:
$user = User::first();
$user->tags()->allRelatedIds(); // select id from related table -> join
```

This is what you may use, but it is not the answer, since you want to eager load those ids.

That being said, you need to create another model for pivot table:

```
// UserTag model
protected $table = 'user_tag';

// this is not required, just to make it read-only
public static function boot()
{
   parent::boot();
   static::saving(function() {
     return false;
   }
}

// User model
public function tagsPivot()
{
   return $this->hasMany('UserTag')->select('tag_id', 'user_id'); // appropriate keys here
}

public function getTagsIds()
{
   return $this->tagsPivot->lists('tag_id');
}

// then you can do this:
$users = User::with('tagsPivot')->get(); // no join, select category_id from pivot table

foreach ($users as $user)
{
   $user->getTagsIds();
}
```

.

---

You can also make some changes on the User model, depending on your liking:

```
// to be able to do this:
$users = User::with('tagsIds')->get();

foreach ($users as $user)
{
   $user->tagsIds;
}

// User model
public function tagsIds()
{
   return $this->hasMany('UserTag')->select('tag_id', 'user_id'); // appropriate keys here
}

public function getTagsIdsAttribute()
{
   if ( ! array_key_exists('tagsIds', $this->relations)) $this->load('tagsIds');

   return $this->getRelation('tagsIds')->lists('tag_id');
}
```

Comment: That's perfect, thank you so much for your effort! I will definitely use this!

Comment: `getRelatedIds` was renamed to `allRelatedIds` recently

Answer (score 1):

Give it a try (not tested):

```
$user = User::query();
$ids = $user->getRelation('tags')->getRelatedIds();
```

Or maybe something like this (but does some extra queries during the `tags` call):

```
$user = User::find(1);
$ids = $user->tags->fetch('id');
```

Update: (Another way)

```
$user = User::find(1);
$ids = array_fetch(DB::table($user->joiningTable('tag'))
                       ->where($user->getForeignKey(), $user->getKey())
                       ->get(), 'tag_id');
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I would suggest (`$user->tags()` will do of course, no need to call the query, and you can't call the relation on that query ;) ), because, like in my comment on the question, there could be inconsistency querying only the pivot table.

Comment: Didn't know about the getRelatedIds() method. Unfortunately, though, the getRelation() method doesn't allow for any constraints on User, so it works on the whole User table only. The second way works, but still does the redundant query on the Tags table. I also assume that what I'm trying to do can't work on collections? You would think this would be built-in to Eloquent, as it's fairly common to grab only the related IDs.

Comment: yes the second one does extra queries and it would be better if we could do similar things easily as a `built-in` feature, maybe there is a way but not exposed yet, all the best :-).

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha thanks for your time! I will keep digging.

Comment: You are most welcome and if you find anything then please don't forget to share, hope you'll come up with something interesting :-)